# Waiting for RabbitMQ docker container to start with docker-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, rabbitmq, integration-testing, docker-maven-plugin

How can I tell `docker-maven-plugin` to wait for the RabbitMQ container to fully start up before running integration tests?

This is the plugin configuration I am using in the `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-rabbitmq-container</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <alias>rabbitmq</alias>
                        <name>rabbitmq:3.6.10-management</name>
                        <run>
                            <log>
                                <prefix>RABBITMQ</prefix>
                                <color>cyan</color>
                            </log>
                            <namingStrategy>alias</namingStrategy>
                            <ports>
                                <port>5672:5672</port>
                                <port>15672:15672</port>
                            </ports>
                        </run>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-rabbitmq-container</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

At the moment the ITs start executing while RabbitMQ it's still initialising and failing as the server is not available.

Comment: Post your docker-compose and Dockerfile

Comment: Just using the rabbitmq:3.6.10-management from Docker Hub to start RabitMQ, no Dockerfile or docker-compose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a more assertive way of checking for the status of RabbitMQ. As I am using the `rabbitmq:3.6.10-management` docker image, I can check that the management url on `localhost:15672` is up:

```
<wait>
    <http>
        <url>http://localhost:15672</url>
        <method>GET</method>
        <status>200..399</status>
    </http>
    <time>10000</time>
</wait>
```

The `wait` configuration will check the return value of getting the management url, for a maximum of 10 seconds until it's within the specified HTTP response status range, but RabbitMQ normally starts up within 2 to 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

"While starting a container is it possible to block the execution until some condition is met"

https://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-wait

You can `wait` for some log output from RabbitMQ container with `log`:

`Regular expression which is applied against the log output of an container and blocks until the pattern is matched. You can use (?s) in the pattern to switch on multi line matching.`

Comment: Thanks @abinet. According to the docs I can `wait` for a specified amount of `time` and block the execution. In the case of the RabbitMQ container, is there a more deterministic way to do that?

Comment: Still no luck at this, I don't think looking at the log to determine if RabbitMQ has started is a good idea.